# Spline interpolation along one dimension of a matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, interpolation

I have a 3-dimensional matrix and want to interpolate the data along the third dimension of this matrix. Of course, the following is possible:

```
I = zeros(3,3,10);
M = rand(3,3,5);
for x = 1:3
    for y = 1:3
        I(x,y,:) = spline(1:5, M(x,y,:), linspace(1,5,10));
    end
end
```

However, these for loops are not very elegant and efficient, especially when the matrix sizes become bigger. 
Is there a way to do the spline interpolation along a specific dimension more efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like calling `spline` directly on `M` does exactly what you want:

```
M = rand(3,3,5);
x = 1:5;
xx = linspace(1,5,10);

%// loop approach
I1 = zeros(3,3,10);
for row = 1:3
    for col = 1:3
        I1(row,col,:) = spline(x, M(row,col,:), xx);
    end
end

%// just calling spline
I2 = spline(x, M, xx);
```

Test for correctness

```
>> isequal(I1,I2)

ans =

     1
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Unfortunately, when I copy your code and execute it as it is, the `isequal(I1,I2)` returns 0. Does anybody else also get 0 as the return value?

Comment: @Ethunxxx that's strange, it definitely returns 1 for me. It could (though I doubt it) be a truncation / precision error due to different environments in which case rather check `all(abs((I1(:)-I2(:)) < 0.000001)`. But otherwise, try opening a clean instance of MATLAB and run the code verbatim. I just ran the code in Octave (via Octave-online) and it returns `1` there as well.

Comment: yes it apparently is a precision related error: `isequal(abs(I1-I2)< 1e-15 , ones(3,3,10))` returns 1!!

Comment: @Ethunxxx I'm very surprised by that. I can't imagine why that would be.

Comment: I don't know either. I'm running Matlab2014a on Ubuntu 14.04. Very strange. Anyway, your answer is simple and correct! Thanks a lot. Apparently, spline by default seems to act on the last dimension, right?

Comment: @Ethunxxx from [the docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/spline.html) *If `Y` is an array that is not a vector,
If `xx` is a scalar or vector, `size(yy)` equals `[d1, d2, ..., dk, length(xx)]`.* which pretty much boils down to `spline` acting on the last dimension, yes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111019/discussion-between-ethunxxx-and-dan).